# update the state of component from another component

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class

```
class TableComponent {
    tableBody
    tableHeader
    tableFooter
}
```

`TableHeader` has a button that should be enabled or disabled depending on the state of `tableBody`

```
class TableHeader {
    button

    void enableButton(false|true)
}
```

To handle this I pass instance of `TableHeader` to `TableBody` like this

```
new TableBody(tableHeader);
```

and inside the `tableBody` I do some actions and invoke `tableHeader.enableButton()`

But is there a way not to pass the reference of `tableHeader` into the body? Would use for example of `EventBus` better? Or for join all table classes into a single class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close to the Observer Pattern already. The missing piece is just to create the Pub/Sub interfaces, so that when you pass the header into the body, you have a layer of abstraction in place that prevents concrete table components from coupling to each other directly.

```
public class MainJava {
    interface Publisher { void subscribe(Subscriber s); }
    interface Subscriber { void update(); }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        TableComponent component = new TableComponent(new TableBody(), new TableHeader(), new TableFooter());
        component.setBodyText("Hello World");
    }

    static class TableComponent {
        final TableBody body;
        final TableHeader header;
        final TableFooter footer;

        public TableComponent(TableBody body, TableHeader header, TableFooter footer) {
            this.body = body;
            this.header = header;
            this.footer = footer;
            body.subscribe(header);
        }
        public void setBodyText(String newBody) {
            body.edit(newBody);
        }
    }

    static class TableBody implements Publisher {
        final Set<Subscriber> subscribers = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
        @Override
        public void subscribe(Subscriber s) {
            subscribers.add(s);
        }
        void edit(String newBody) {
            System.out.println(newBody);
            subscribers.forEach(Subscriber::update);
        }
    }
    static class TableHeader implements Subscriber {
        @Override
        public void update() {
            System.out.println("Toggle Button");
        }
    }
    static class TableFooter {}
}
```

Although the line `body.subscribe(header);` may appear no different from `new TableBody(tableHeader);` it's critical in the former that `body` sees `header` only as a `Subscriber` whereas in the latter `body` is aware that `header` is a `TableHeader`. That layer of abstraction is the difference between tight coupling and loose coupling.

Comment: So this approach is better than using event bus?

Comment: Since the question is tagged `design-patterns` consider how you would implement an eventbus. As a Singleton? So if we rephrase the question as, _is Observer better than Singleton_, I can say unequivocally yes. But of course the real answer to any subjective question about "_better_" is, _it depends_.

Comment: I see. So basically I need to make into publisher any item that might lead to change in table header?

Comment: Yes, but I would try to think about it at a higher level: any object that has interesting events to broadcast can be a Publisher. Any object interested in one or more events can be a Subscriber. Try to avoid putting knowledge of headers or bodies into the events.